# HTML5+php внедрение

Tags: framework, html, cms, шаблоны, php

Возможно ли как-то реализовать, к примеру, форму `registration/auth` на `php` в `html` сайт?

Comment: Да, возможно.

Comment: Если не трудно, кратко обьясните или наводку какую нибудь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вариант - использовать iframe, в который подгружать php-документ. Вариант второй - 
чтобы в HTML мог исполняться php, создайте в корне сайта файл .htaccess и добавьте строку:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php .html .shtml .htm
```

Ну и самый простой, на мой взгляд - поменять расширение html в php